# two plugins difference in maven's pom

Tags: maven, selenium, junit, pom.xml

Maybe at the beginning that question is stupid and i get minuses but..
please tell me which one plugin code should i use ?

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.5</source>
      <target>1.5</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

or

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <!-- put your configurations here -->
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the second one, especially if you use maven 3.

It is a good practice to explicitly specify the `groupId` so that there is no confusion.  Some plugins are available from `org.codehaus.mojo`, for instance.  Maven does resolve the plugin as documented [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html).

`version` is relevant if you are using maven3, as described [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-AutomaticPluginVersionResolution).

You would still specify the source/target versions in either case, if you want it to be different from the jdk you are using.

Answer (score 3):

- The groupId is optional since org.apache.maven.plugins is the default
  groupID, yet I would recommend keeping it around anyway
- You should always use the version tag to pin down the plugin
  version and avoid surprises regarding regressions introduced in newer
  plugins.
- If you are sure about the JDK you develop for, you should definitely
  specify the source and target version

So use a combination of the above IMHO